# Multiple "params" in Snakemake file

Tags: snakemake

I've got the following Snakemake file:

```
rule test:
    params:
        a = "a"
    shell:
        "echo {params.a}"
```

Which works as expected:

```
$ snakemake
```

> a

But when I add a second parameter, I get an error:

```
rule test:
    params:
        a = "a"
        b = 5
    shell:
        "echo {params.a} {params.b}"
```

> SyntaxError in line 4 of /home/mschu/Code/snakemake/Snakefile:
>   invalid syntax

Why is that?

The [documentation](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#non-file-parameters-for-rules) also has only examples with only one item in `params`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate them by a comma:

```
rule test:
    params:
        a = "a",
        b = 5
    shell:
        "echo {params.a} {params.b}"
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks!